# Create UIPopOver without including Tableview in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, ios6

I want to create two `PopOvers` when at the time button clicked and `textField` clicked in the same `UIView` (not `ViewController`). In those popovers I need to load separate array values. Is there any way to create them and added to `UIView`?

I already added one `tableview` for base `UIView`, so without using `tableviews`, how can I create `UIpopOvers` and load the arrays in those `popOvers`? How to handle the selected rows?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) can help you to create a `popover menu`.

Or you can take an `UIImageView` having shape of `popover menu` and table view in that, it will be  easy to load arrays and to handle selected rows.

I did the same using second method.

Happy Coding!